# IEnumerable string join in C# .NetStandard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to write a library with .NetStandard 2.0, and apparently there's not an overload for the `string.Join` method that accepts an IEnumerable. This code works fine in .NetCore 2.0, but not standard:

```
string.Join('/', parts.Skip(index))
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: What does " but not standard" mean? .Net Core 2.0 is an implementation of .Net Standard 2 as is .Net Framework 4.6.1. Your question doesn't make sense

Comment: My .NET Standard 2.0 project has a `string.Join(string, IEnumerable<string>)` overload... Maybe you need `string.Substring` for the `parts.Skip` instead?

Comment: According to the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netstandard-2.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) that overload exists. Include a [MCVE] with your question so we can attempt to reproduce your problem.  I imagine parts is not a IEnumerable<string>

Comment: @maccettura look very carefully - slightly different overload, and eltiare isn't wrong: it is missing, but not *very* missing

Comment: I'm trying to make a .NetStandard library off of something I built using .NetCore and I'm getting an error on this line. It says there's no suitable overload. From my reading of the docs it seems like it should be there.

Comment: @MarcGravell oh good eye. Although does the char overload exist in regular .NET anyway?  I don’t ever remember using that (on mobile now so hard to lookup)

Comment: @maccettura yes; it does feel rather unnecessary, though, to be fair

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overload exists with a `string separator` instead of just `char separator`:

```
string s = string.Join("/", parts.Skip(index));
```

so... use that?

Comment: @RonBeyer what makes you say that? I'm assuming that `parts` is `IEnumerable<string>` ? are you suggesting that `parts` is actually a `string`?

Comment: I suppose you may be right (without having the OP clarify) that `parts` is an `IEnumerable<string>`, I guess I assumed it was a single string.

Comment: Parts is an IEnumerable<string>, and I'm getting the error reported in JetBrains rider on Mac. I should probably do a clean and rebuild just to make sure...

Comment: @eltiare I span up a new `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>` library project and it seems to work fine *as long as* you use a `string` for the separator...

Comment: There we go. That fixed it. Weird that it works in .NetCore but not .NetStandard.

Answer (score 5):

To add a bit of context to the answer by Marc Gravell: .NET Standard and .NET Core have a different set of APIs.

.NET Standard represents a set of APIs that need to be implemented by a platform if it supports a version of .NET Standard.

.NET Core is a platform that implements .NET Standard. In addition to those APIs, it implements a few more.

The APIs available on .NET Standard for `string.Join` are (from https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/netstandard/ref/mscorlib.cs):

```
    public static System.String Join(System.String separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> values) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join(System.String separator, params object[] values) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join(System.String separator, params string[] value) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join(System.String separator, string[] value, int startIndex, int count) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join<T>(System.String separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> values) { throw null; }
```

For .NET Core, the set of APIs is bigger since APIs were added to the .NET Core platform but not to .NET Standard (from https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime/ref/System.Runtime.cs#L2307):

```
    public static System.String Join(char separator, params object[] values) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join(char separator, params string[] value) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join(char separator, string[] value, int startIndex, int count) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join(System.String separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> values) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join(System.String separator, params object[] values) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join(System.String separator, params string[] value) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join(System.String separator, string[] value, int startIndex, int count) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join<T>(char separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> values) { throw null; }
    public static System.String Join<T>(System.String separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> values) { throw null; }
```

If you are targeting .NET Core, you can use the overload that takes a `char`. 
If you are targeting .NET Standard, you can use the overload that takes a `string`.